# winforms adjust controls to push up vertically when others are invisible

Tags: c#, winforms

I've create a c# winforms form,

It has a bunch of labels positioned and a flowlayoutpanel.

on certain occasions i set one of the labels and the flowlayoutpanel to visible =false.

As a result i want all labels beneath them to be pushed up - at the moment there is a gap where they were.

Also, I'd like the flowlayoutpanel to grow and shrink depending on the number of items it has.
at the moment it is just the size i set it to be in the designer.

please can you help with these 2 issues.

Thanks

Comment: you may use some panels to divide your form, then hide each panel then needed and use the dock.fill property. when you'll hide a panel, the other two will fill the empty space left.

Answer (score 9):

If I got you correctly, I would suggest using a TableLayoutPane with two rows. The top row will contain a docked panel with all the controls that may be hidden. The bottom row will contain a docked panel with all the rest.

Set the top row's SizeType to AutoSize and the bottom row's to 100%.

When you want to hide the controls, set the top panel's Visible property to false. Now, because the top row is AutoSized it will shrink to nothing, causing the bottom row to "jump" up.

Comment: I didn't got it: how can I set a properties of a row? It seem to be neither in the properties windows, nor in popup of the «tableLayoutPanel» object.

Comment: Just to add one thing, because I tried what you suggested but it didn't work until I set this `AutoSizeMode="GrowAndShrink"` for TableLayoutPanel

Answer (score 1):

The TableLayoutPanel does the pushing. Maybe you can use that if there is no better answer in next time.

Answer (score 1):

First problem:
You may use some simple panels to divide your form, give them the `dock.fill` property. when you'll hide a panel programmatically, the other panels will fill the empty space left.

Second problem:
You have to set the `Autosize` property to `true`.