# TableLayout filling the whole space when one of the two is invisible

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayout, fill, autosize

In Winforms, I have 2 tableLayout A and B sharing the same space. I would like to switch between them (e.g. via a button), only one visible at a time so that they fill the same space.

What I have tried, following [some post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327400/winforms-adjust-controls-to-push-up-vertically-when-others-are-invisible) : put them both into another TableLayout X as container, with 2 rows, the first row Autosize and the second put as Fill.

I managed to achieve the following : when A is invisible, row 1 Autosize reduce the size to 0 and bring B up, filling all space. But when B is invisible, A does not take all the space.

How can I make A to take all the space ?

Thank you.

Here is what happens when A alone is visible

[image: A visible]

Here is what happens when B alone is visible

[image: B visible]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following in my application. I have to show forms one by one in table lay out. For that, I removed the control(form1),from first row and added another control(form2) to the same row.So,you should also try like this with tablelayout control.

```
  var control = tableLayoutPanel23.GetControlFromPosition(0, 1);
  tableLayoutPanel23.Controls.Remove(control);//removed form1
  tableLayoutPanel23.Controls.Add(frm2, 0, 1);//added form2
  frm1.Dispose();
  frm2.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be 1 tableLayoutPanel which should have 2 rows and 2 group box in each rows. You can make both the groupbox dock property as fill. Inside You can pro-grammatically change the height of the row by using:

```
tableLayoutPanel3.RowStyles[0].Height = 0;
```

Thus when A is invisible B will take the full size of the tableLayoutPanel and vice versa. In case both groupbox visible then the group box will take the size of each row of the tableLayoutPanel: